# How to use where in statement in codeigniter with pair of values from multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have the following array:

```
$chain_combination = array (array('a','b'), array ('c','d'), array('e','f'));
```

How I can make the following query in codeigniter by using the $chain_combination array?

```
SELECT  *
FROM    table
WHERE   (column1, column2) IN (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e','f'))
```

Comment: Thing IN doesnt work that way. You can only use one field with IN so do it for each field an concate them with OR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(array('a','b'), array ('c','d'), array('e','f'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);


$out = array();
foreach( $arr as $key=>$val ) {
    if( is_array($val) ) {
        $out[] = "('".implode("','",$val)."')";
    }   
}    

$final = implode(",",$out);

print_r($final);


//out: ('a','b'),('c','d'),('e','f')
```

with foreach and implode